# AI2Canvas plugin support for Adobe Illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export

Is that possible to somehow run [AI2Canvas plugin](http://visitmix.com/labs/ai2canvas/) in Illustrator CS6? I used it in CS5 version successfully and it did its job just great, but now when I start Illustrator, it shows an alert that it can't load the plugin and it doesn't appear in export options as a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of the Ai->Canvas plug-in, and I'm just about to release a version that's compatible with Adobe Illustrator CS6. It'll run on both Mac and PC (32-bit and 64-bit). I'd suggest watching [my blog](http://blog.mikeswanson.com/) for updates.

Answer (score 1):

No. Plug in architecture changed with Illustrator CS6 and its move to 64-bit.

You need to contact the manufacturer and see if they are going to update their plug in.

There's nothing you can do as a user other than to use an older version of Illustrator if you need the plug in.